# Dynamic Slideshow using Applescript

Tags: applescript, slideshow

I have a folder of images that gets updated from a camera taking pictures periodically throughout the day.  I'm trying to write some applescript that will create a slideshow from a folder of images but also update as more are added without having to rerun the script.  I started out trying to do quick look but couldn't get that working.  Any ideas on how best to tackle this?

**UPDATE**
this is what I have hacked together so far:

```
tell application "Finder" to set the_folder to get folder (choose folder)
tell application "Finder" to open the_folder

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        key code 124
        keystroke "a" using command down
        keystroke " " using option down
    end tell
end tell
```

I don't believe this works if I add photos behind the scenes though.

Comment: What makes the slides advance - a timer or keypresses? How configurable does it need to be? Is it full-screen images - I mean do you change the desktop background or overlay images?

Comment: I was really going for simplicity... which is why I was trying to use the quick look feature.  That uses a standard 3 second delay and takes the images full screen... similar to command+'a' then option+"(space)" :)  The problem is I don't think quick look works with adding more items since it starts off with a selection of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with and it works perfectly for what I need.

```
tell application "Finder" to set the_folder to get folder (choose folder)
tell application "Finder" to open the_folder

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        key code 124
        keystroke "a" using command down
        keystroke " " using option down
    end tell
end tell

repeat while true
    delay 60
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Finder"
            keystroke "a" using command down
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```

A few caveats... since it is using quick look, you can't really do anything on the computer while this is running since it can't have any other app activate while it is running (quick look closes when this happens).  Also the repeat section is required to get quick look to pickup the new additions to the directory without losing focus.  Pretty nasty stuff, but I couldn't really find another easy way to do it!